# How can Naruto breathe on the moon?

Tags: naruto

In *The Last: Naruto the Movie*, Naruto's fight with Toneri is set on the moon.

But how can he breathe on the moon? Is that because of some technique, or something else?

Comment: he have Alien blood/soul/chakra in him . . .

Comment: Alien? In Naruto Universe?

Comment: The Naruto Universe is pretty weird, so I wouldn't be surprised if that was true. Plus in the Naruto wiki it says that Kaguya Ōtsutsuki is an alien, so it's not that surprising.

Comment: Oh, lol, I forgot about Kaguya, my bad! xD

Comment: @JTR case point the only 2 people have Alien Chakra (Naruto & Sasuke) is stupidly overpowered at the end of manga/anime

Comment: i was sure that kaguya's chakra came from the Chakra fruit, which was from a tree on earth. she even had children, both male, so she reproduced with presumably a Human male, something only another human can do (asexual reproduction is a CLONE, so it cant be male). It makes no sense for her to be alien.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In short

According to wiki:

> The exterior of the Moon is barren, covered with craters and canyons.
> It has a weak gravity, **but is still able to maintain a breathable**
> **atmosphere**
> .

Since it has **breathable atmosphere**, so that's why Naruto didn't used any technique or something else. Which conclude that the Moon from shinobi world is far more different than the real moon which we know.

For more information regarding this you can see this [link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Moon).

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying that the Naruto universe is not our own, and thus their moon is different. Also, all the spoilers ahead.

The moon in the Naruto universe was made by the Sage of the Six Paths, Hagoromo, when he and Hamura sealed Kaguya. The moon was made via Chibaku Tensei, which is a gravitational ninjutsu that turns an object into a "gravity core", which then attracts the matter around it into a large, circular object. You'll remember Pain using it on Naruto to capture the Nine Tails. Theoretically, it's possible that the moon has an atmosphere by capturing part of their Earth's atmosphere in the creation of the moon, being attracted to it via the intense gravity/immense power of the Sage's and Hamura's joint Chibaku Tensei. This would allow him to breath there, and since he didn't instantly suffocate on arrival I'd guess there was enough atmosphere from the formation to sustain at least his body.

[Chibaku Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_%E2%80%94_Chibaku_Tensei)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case we should consider that they're in a world totally different from ours, what means that their moon surface and structure are different from ours as well.

Some say that their moon was created to keep criminals arrested, but in that scenario we do have an atmosphere kindly similar to Earth's.

This isn't so insane to think of when considering the other movies where some characters could breath inside the water, or things like that.

About Kaguya, she wasn't an alien, she was a common woman that ate the fruit and absorbed the tree's power. :)

Comment: You should consider answering this question by relating it with some given facts. Also kaguya is an alien (see in kaguya wiki page) which is also stated by Ms steel comment. So I am not sure that you are giving right answer and also it seems like you simply made an assumption

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly sure why all of the answers have resolved around the fact that the Naruto universe has a moon that is completely different from our own - it's more of a cop out, rather than a fully thought through answer. Although, I'm not saying it's completely wrong, as it could be plausible.

Considering it is the Naruto universe, filled with chakra and the abilities to use this chakra to create giant masses of elements, then it's pretty safe to assume that Naruto and Toneri were either subconsciously using a jutsu that created/utilised oxygen and allowed them to breath, or, with the power of the nine tails (in Naruto's case) and the large mass of chakra handed down through generations of the Otsutsuki family (in Toneri's case), allowing their bodies to operate fully by using chakra, instead of usual body functions.

Comment: It could also be Toneri using a jutsu that allowed everyone on the moon to breath, or he used a jutsu that created air, since Hinata and her sister (forgotten her name) were also on the moon before Naruto's arrival.

Comment: ' Subconsciously ' I don't think so. According to the given question he is asking that Naruto used any techniques to breathe at moon and the simple answer for this question is no because there moon has atmosphere. See wiki page its already written. Also he didn't ask that how moon has atmosphere and about chakra importance on moon. So its better to limit answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well , Naruto can breathe on moon because it is anime logic.
The creators doesn't want to complicate the situation too much and probably thought that they could just leave out the part where humans can't breathe on the moon.

Normally, we call this anime logic.